# Showing that $40^{\circ}$ is not constructible

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Show that $40^{\circ}$ is not constructible.

**Attempt**

We note that $\cos 120^{\circ}=-\frac{1}{2}$ and that it also equals $4\cos^340^{\circ}-3\cos40^{\circ}$, which is obtained by using the cosine triple angle formula on $\cos(3\cdot 40^{\circ})$.

Equating this I get that $0=8\cos^3 40^{\circ}-6\cos40^{\circ}+1$.

So this means that $\alpha=\cos40^{\circ}$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x)=8x^3-6x+1$.

If I can show that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then I'm done, but I am having a bit of difficulty showing it is irreducible.

Eisenstein's Criterion isn't applicable here. I've tried messing with the modular $p$ test with values $p=3, 5, 7$ but didn't really help. I also tried showing that $f(x)$ must be a product of a linear and a quadratic polynomial but I couldn't reach a contradiction after equating the coefficients. Any hints to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you have the first sentence backwards. $120^\circ$ is easily constructible, it is double the angle of an equilateral triangle. Depending upon what your book has done so far, it is enough to show your polynomial is irreducible. Rational Roots Theorem.

Comment: By the Rational Root Theorem, the only possible rational roots of $f(x)$ are $\pm1, \pm\frac{1}{2}, \pm\frac{1}{4}, \pm\frac{1}{8}$. Evaluating $f(x)$ at each of these possible roots finds no zero, so there is no linear factor with rational coefficients. Thus the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Ah, thanks @ Will and @ Steve. I just looked up the Rational Root Theorem. I've used it before but didn't realize it had a name.

Comment: Since you did not mention it, have you tried Gauss's lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answering this to take it out of the Unanswered Queue**

By the Rational Root Theorem, the only possible rational roots of $f(x)$ are $\pm1,\pm\frac12,\pm\frac14,\pm\frac18$. Evaluating $f(x)$ at each of these possible roots finds no zero, so there is no linear factor with rational coefficients. Thus the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.